# Update picklist value after commandButton onclick event

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, controller, extension

I have two buttons on my visualforce page:

```
<apex:form >
         <apex:commandButton styleclass="btn-lg btn-data" value="Value 1" onclick="setValue1()"/>
         <apex:commandButton styleclass="btn-lg btn-data" value="Value 2" onclick="setValue2()"/>
</apex:form>
```

Upon clicking "Value 1", I need a picklist (Choice) to change to "Value 1" in my custom object (Options__c). I need the same to be done when clicking "Value 2". Both values are choices on the same picklist (Choice).

How would I do this this in my extension?

Answer (score 1):

Change you VF code to call action functions on your extension instead of using the javascript onclick attributes:

```
<apex:form >
     <apex:commandButton styleclass="btn-lg btn-data" value="Value 1" action="{!setValue1}"/>
     <apex:commandButton styleclass="btn-lg btn-data" value="Value 2" action="{!setValue2}"/>
</apex:form>
```

And then create 2 functions in your extension class:

```
public void setValue1() {
    opt.Choice__c = 'Value 1';
}
public void setValue1() {
    opt.Choice__c = 'Value 1';
}
```

The above code assumes your Options__c instance is called "opt".

### Update

Try this as your controller:

```
public class detailExt {

    public Options__c opt {get; set;}

    public myControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        opt = (Options__c)stdController.getRecord();
    }

    public void setValue1() {
        opt.Choice__c = 'Value 1';
    }
    public void setValue2() {
        opt.Choice__c = 'Value 2';
    }

}
```

I think your VF page will need to reference {!opt} anywhere it wants to reference the Options__c object, so for example:

```
<apex:outputField value="{!opt.Choice__c}" />
```

Comment: Thanks! Still having trouble constructing the extension. Look below for my code so far.